# Unit test passes in debug build but fails in release build

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

I have written a unit test for an asynchronous class member. The test passes as expected when I execute my test under "Debug build". However, it hangs the CPU (while loop is deadlocked) when I execute my test under "Release build".

If I specifically configure the Unit test project with Debug build (that is Debug build unit test assembly and Release build target assembly), the test passes as well.

Code to Test

```
    public override void DoSomething(object parameter)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncDoSomething, parameter);
    }

    private void AsyncDoSomething(object parameter)
    {
        //Doing something
                .....

        //Something is done
        RaiseSomethingIsDone();
    }
```

My Unit Test

```
    public void DoingSomethingTest()
    {
        bool IsSomethingDone = false;

        //Setup
        //Doing some setup here.
        target.SomethingDone += (sender, args) =>
            {
                IsSomethingDone = true;
            };

        //Exercise
        target.DoSomething(_someParameter);
        while (!IsSomethingDone ){}

        //Verify
        //Doing some asserts here.
    }
```

Here is the IL generated by the C# compiler under Debug configuration and Release configuration:

Debug while loop IL interpenetration:

```
  IL_00cb:  ldloc.s    'CS$<>8__locals7'
  IL_00cd:  ldfld      bool IsSomethingDone
  IL_00d2:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_00d3:  ceq
  IL_00d5:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
  IL_00d7:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
  IL_00d9:  brtrue.s   IL_00c9
```

Release while loop IL interpenetration:

```
  IL_00bc:  ldloc.s    'CS$<>8__locals7'
  IL_00be:  ldfld      bool IsSomethingDone
  IL_00c3:  brfalse.s  IL_00bc
```

I understand there are better ways to synchronize the test thread to the background ThreadPool thread.

My questions are

1. why is the release build not working? The flag IsSomethingDone is not set by the worker thread.
2. Is it because the eventhandler (the lambda expression) does not get executed?
3. Is the event not raised correctly?

By the way, I verified that DoSomething is executed correctly and generated the correct result.

**Follow up Questions:**

1. Should one build unit test projects under Debug Build or Release Build ?
2. Should one test the target assembly under Debug Build or Release Build ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flag `IsSomethingDone` is being cached in a CPU register, and never reloaded from memory, so that when one thread modifies it, the other never sees the modified value.
This is an optimization which the .NET JIT compiler does, so you'd need to look at the actual x86/x64 binary dissasembly to see this, MSIL is not deep enough :-)

The solution is to mark your flag as `volatile`

This is a textbook example of one of the kind of multithreading bugs that can occur. So much so, that here's a link to part of a presentation I did at TechEd New Zealand 2012 on this exact subject. Hopefully it should explain what's going on in more detail

http://orionedwards.blogspot.co.nz/2012/09/teched-2012-background-2-compiler.html

As you have mentioned, you can't put `volatile` on a local variable, but you should be able to use `Thread.VolatileRead` instead.

I'd suggest not using this design at all - your main thread is going to spin using 100% CPU until your worker completes, which is horrible. A better solution is to use a `ManualResetEvent` (or other kind of signaling mechanism).

Here's an example

```
public void DoingSomethingTest()
{
    var done = new ManualResetEvent(false); // initially not set

    //Setup
    //Doing some setup here.
    target.SomethingDone += (sender, args) =>
        {
            done.Set();
        };

    //Exercise
    target.DoSomething(_someParameter);
    done.WaitOne(); // waits until Set is called. You can specify an optional timeout too which is nice

    //Verify
    //Doing some asserts here.
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did to fix this problem.

Comment: I also tried Thread.VolatileRead, which does the trick too. But conveniently, there isnt an overloaded VolatileRead for boolean type. Yeah!! more typing.

Comment: The reason why I posted this question, is to understand why the release build didnot work. I guess MSIL isnot deep enough indeed.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any locking (or other memory barrier), I believe `IsSomethingDone`  would need to be declared as `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, Mitch. You cannot declare local variable volatile.

Comment: @MitchWheat - you mention that volatile is going to be deprecated. Really? I haven't heard of that - do you have any links to information?

Comment: I vaguely remember Eric Lippert mentioning it...I'd have to search...hmmmm..can't find anything concrete...was it a  dream!

Comment: `volatile` becoming deprecated doesn't make much sense. It's quite important in lock-free code.